# Use identity column to create select with a dynamic number of rows based on the number of repeats in a surrogate?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

thanks in advance,

I'm trying to create a view that, in part, selects from a very basic table, comments:

```
    Surrogate |  line_num  |     Comment
    1         |     1      |   QTY - 10
    1         |     2      |   Serial 12345 
    1         |     3      |   Serial 53234
    2         |     4      |   QTY - 5
    3         |     5      |   QTY - 6
    4         |     6      |   QTY - 7
    4         |     7      |   Serial 14455
```

The surrogates are defined elsewhere, the line_num is the identity column. The above is a representative sample, but some of the surrogates have up to ten comments. I need the select (as the point is to go into a SQL View) statement to return:

```
    Surrogate    |    Comment 1    |    Comment 2    |    Comment 3
    1            |    QTY - 10     |    Serial 12345 |  Serial 53234
    2            |    QTY - 5      |                 |
    3            |    QTY - 6      |                 |
    4            |    QTY - 7      |    Serial 14455 |
```

I looked into the pivot command but it didn't appear to be what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thanks in advance, I've looked for awhile but can't seem to find anything quite like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot` or conditional aggregation.  However, you need to assign a row number.  Here is the conditional aggregation approach:

```
select surrogate,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then comment end) as Comment1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then comment end) as Comment2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then comment end) as Comment3
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by surrogate order by line_num) as seqnum
      from basictable t
     ) t
group by surrogate;
```

You can use a similar subquery with `pivot`.